# Llenado de datos en Datatable con parametros

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

me he topado con este problema, quiero mostrar datos de una consulta MySQL en un Datatable, pero me sale este error: **Uncaught TypeError: n[v] is undefined**, les paso el código a ver si me ayudan a resolver esto, desde ya les estoy muy agradecido.

```
$('#frmReporteVenta').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   let varEmpresa = $('#txtEmpresasRpt').val();
   let varCliente = $('#txtClientesRpt').val();
   let varFechaIni = $('#txtFechaInicioRpt').val();
   let varFechaFin = $('#txtFechaFinRpt').val();

   llenarReporte(varEmpresa, varCliente, varFechaIni, varFechaFin);
});

function llenarReporte(empresa, cliente, fechaini, fechafin) {

   let varEmpresa = empresa;
   let varCliente = cliente;
   let varFechaIni = fechaini;
   let varFechaFin = fechafin;
   let datos = { 'varEmpresa': varEmpresa, 'varCliente': varCliente, 'varFechaIni': varFechaIni, 'varFechaFin': varFechaFin };
   let urlAjaxReporte = base_url + "Pedidos/getInfoReportes";

   let tblReporteVentas = $('#tblReporteVentas').DataTable({
       "aProcessing": true, 
       "aServerSide": true,
       "language": {
           "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
       },
       "ajax": {
           "url": urlAjaxReporte,
           "type": 'post',
           "data": datos
       },
       "columns": [
           {"data": "fecha_entrega"},
           {"data": "empresa"},
           {"data": "cliente"},
           {"data": "dni"},
           {"data": "comensal"},
           {"data": "entrada"},
           {"data": "fondo"},
           {"data": "postre"},
           {"data": "total"}
       ],
       "responsive": "true",
       "bDestroy": true,
       "iDisplayLength": 10,
       "order": [[0, "desc"]]
   });

}
```

La consulta está testeada, no tiene errores, la variable base_url también funciona, la uso en todo el proyecto.

Espero que me puedan ayudar con esto. Muchas gracias.

---

He cambiado un poco el código, estoy guardando el resultado de la consulta en una variable y luego lo paso al Datatable. Lo que recibe la variable es esto:

```
[{"fecha_entrega":"2022-11-28","dni":"70167051","comensal":"JOSE LUIS, TORRES SHUPINGAHUA","entrada":"Papa a la huancaina","fondo":"Arroz chaufa con pollo","postre":"Torta de chocolate","empresa":"Enotria","cliente":"Enotria","total":"16"}]
```

Y lo pongo en el Datatable así:

```
$('#frmReporteVenta').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   let urlAjaxReporte = base_url + "/Pedidos/getInfoReportes";
   let data = $('#frmReporteVenta').serialize();

   $.ajax({
       url: urlAjaxReporte, 
       type: 'post',
       data: data,
       success: function(response) {
           let datos = response;

           $('#tblReporteVentas').DataTable({
               language: {
                   "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
               },
               data: datos,
               columns: [
                   {"data": "fecha_entrega"},
                   {"data": "empresa"},
                   {"data": "cliente"},
                   {"data": "dni"},
                   {"data": "comensal"},
                   {"data": "entrada"},
                   {"data": "fondo"},
                   {"data": "postre"},
                   {"data": "total"}
               ],
               responsive: "true",
               bDestroy: true,
               iDisplayLength: 10,
               order: [[0, "desc"]]
           });
       }
   });
```

Y me sale un error que dice esto: **DataTables warning: table id=tblReporteVentas - Requested unknown parameter 'fecha_entrega' for row 0, column 0.**

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Amigo creo que el error es en el tipo de peticion, estas haciendo una peticion POST, en el ajax del data table el type deberia de ser GET.

Comment: Pero en la función del controlador lo hago con POST

Comment: Bueno viendo el codigo intentas realizar un registro de algunos datos y retornar la respuesta en el datatable, lo que retorne la funcion deberia de ser un arreglo asociativo [ {"fecha_entrega": "2022-12-02" , "empresa": "empresa1" , ... ], asegurate de que la funcion retorne los datos de esa manera, de igual forma, pienso que lo mejor seria procesar los datos del registro en un fetch y el resultado de este mostrarlos en el datatable, tendrias mas control sobre la peticion, para manejar los errores. [doc](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Comment: El resultado de la consulta se devuelve en formato json, en el caso que recupere los datos en una variable, de que manera puedo llenar el datatable con los datos metidos en esa variable?

Answer (score 0):

Imprimi el mismo codigo que tienes con la estructura que compartes y el datatable funciona, por el mensaje

> *unknown parameter 'fecha_entrega' for row 0, column 0*

sucede que en algun momento el arreglo no llega con la misma estructura, es decir el campo ***"fecha_entrega"*** llega vacio, observa el ejemplo que hice mas abajo, sale el mismo error, entonces, podrias manipular al momento de traer la respuesta los datos para que se muestre de manera correcta. Puedes verificar, imprimiendo todos los datos por medio de postman, ahi te muestra la respuesta y sabes bien donde se encuentra el error.

```
        {
          "":"2022-11-28",
          "dni":"70167051",
          "comensal":"JOSE LUIS, TORRES SHUPINGAHUA",
          "entrada":"Papa a la huancaina",
          "fondo":"Arroz chaufa con pollo",
          "postre":"Torta de chocolate",
          "empresa":"Enotria",
          "cliente":"Enotria",
          "total":"16"
        },
```

*fragmento de datos sin el encabezado "fecha_entrega"*

```js
// datos con la estructura que estas enviando
let datos = [
        {
          "":"2022-11-28",
          "dni":"70167051",
          "comensal":"JOSE LUIS, TORRES SHUPINGAHUA",
          "entrada":"Papa a la huancaina",
          "fondo":"Arroz chaufa con pollo",
          "postre":"Torta de chocolate",
          "empresa":"Enotria",
          "cliente":"Enotria",
          "total":"16"
        },
        {
          "fecha_entrega":"2022-11-28",
          "dni":"70167051",
          "comensal":"JOSE LUIS, TORRES SHUPINGAHUA",
          "entrada":"Papa a la huancaina",
          "fondo":"Arroz chaufa con pollo",
          "postre":"Torta de chocolate",
          "empresa":"Enotria",
          "cliente":"Enotria",
          "total":"16"
        },
                      {
          "fecha_entrega":"2022-11-28",
          "dni":"70167051",
          "comensal":"JOSE LUIS, TORRES SHUPINGAHUA",
          "entrada":"Papa a la huancaina",
          "fondo":"Arroz chaufa con pollo",
          "postre":"Torta de chocolate",
          "empresa":"Enotria",
          "cliente":"Enotria",
          "total":"16"
        },
        {
          "fecha_entrega":"2022-11-28",
          "dni":"70167051",
          "comensal":"JOSE LUIS, TORRES SHUPINGAHUA",
          "entrada":"Papa a la huancaina",
          "fondo":"Arroz chaufa con pollo",
          "postre":"Torta de chocolate",
          "empresa":"Enotria",
          "cliente":"Enotria",
          "total":"16"
        }
];

$(document).ready(function () {
  // se crea el datatable
  $('#tblReporteVentas').DataTable({
       "aProcessing": true, 
       "aServerSide": true,
       data: datos,
       "language": {
           "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
       },
       "columns": [
           {"data": "fecha_entrega"},
           {"data": "empresa"},
           {"data": "cliente"},
           {"data": "dni"},
           {"data": "comensal"},
           {"data": "entrada"},
           {"data": "fondo"},
           {"data": "postre"},
           {"data": "total"}
       ],
       "responsive": "true",
       "bDestroy": true,
       "iDisplayLength": 10,
       order: [[0, "desc"]]
   });
   
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="tblReporteVentas" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>fecha_entrega</th>
            <th>empresa</th>
            <th>cliente</th>
            <th>dni</th>
            <th>comensal</th>
            <th>entrada</th>
            <th>fondo</th>
            <th>postre</th>
            <th>total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Ok, pero a ti si te sale al final la tabla con los datos, a mi me sale esto en consola

Uncaught TypeError: n[v] is undefined

Comment: Algo más debo estar haciendo mal porque a mi no me muestra ningún resultado, a pesar que en el console si muestra todos los registros